# Dialog selection Criteria

Tags: axapta, x++

When we create a dialog, how do we get the selection criteria for the record (Select button) and how do we disable the select button on the Dialog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you use the [`RunBase` framework](http://www.axaptapedia.com/RunBaseBatch#Query).

For the dialog part of your question see [Axapta Dialog Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702347/axapta-dialog-validation).

To show the query dialog, you must provide two methods:

```
public boolean showQueryValues()
{
    return true;
}
```

and

```
public QueryRun queryRun()
{
    return queryRun;
}
```

The `queryRun` method must return a valid non-null value.

The `queryRun` instance variable is usually assigned a value in the `unpack` and `initParmDefault` methods.

Take a look on the `CustInterestCancel` class for a concise example.

How to disable the select button: return false from `showQueryValues`.

Comment: i had read this somewhere , but forgotten .. Thanks for reminding me :)